# Barcode & Qr code scanning not working with CameraX / ZXing

Tags: android, kotlin, zxing

I'm trying to implement a QR Code + Barcode scanning function in my application but I only manage to scan QR codes.

I'm using ZXing as scanning library and CameraX for camera functions. In order to analyse the image capture by CameraX, I use a custom ImageAnalysis.Analyzer class to detect and decode QR codes + barcode (which is not working).

Here is my analyzer :

```java
class MyCodeImageAnalyzer(
    private val onCodeDetected: (code: Result) -> Unit
) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private val yuvFormats = mutableListOf(YUV_420_888)

    init {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            yuvFormats.addAll(listOf(YUV_422_888, YUV_444_888))
        }
    }

    private val reader = MultiFormatReader()

    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        // We are using YUV format because, ImageProxy internally uses ImageReader to get the image
        // by default ImageReader uses YUV format unless changed.

        if (image.format !in yuvFormats) {
            Timber.e("QRCodeAnalyzer Expected YUV, now = ${image.format}")
            return
        }

        val data = image.planes[0].buffer.toByteArray()

        val source = PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(
            data,
            image.width,
            image.height,
            0,
            0,
            image.width,
            image.height,
            false
        )

        val binaryBitmap = BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source))
        try {
            // Whenever reader fails to detect a QR code in image
            // it throws NotFoundException
            val result = reader.decode(binaryBitmap)
            onCodeDetected(result)
        } catch (e: NotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        image.close()
    }
}
```

I use the MultiFormatReader which takes in account many formats including QR code and barcode.
I think the problem is in the yuvFormats list but I don't know what to add in it.

Comment: How do you configure ZXing? And also, whats the size of the frame?

Comment: I don't think these information will help you.
Concerning ZXing I use the MultiFormatReader in this class thats it.

Comment: I have previously worked with ZXing and that information IS REALLY helpful. Depending on the configuration and the frame size the detection can be fast/slow or good/bad.

Comment: Detection is very fast for QR code but as I said Barcode is not recognized.

Comment: Then I suggest you to configure ZXing to search only the codes you need instead of the default implementation that maybe be too slow for you. Also confirm that the barcode you are trying to read is well-formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scan QR/Barcodes using Google ML Kit.

Please take a look on my article [here](https://proandroiddev.com/building-barcode-qr-code-scanner-for-android-using-google-ml-kit-and-camerax-220b2852589e). Where you can see how to create Barcode scanner using Google ML Kit and Jetpack CameraX .

It's the most updated way to handle it and it's too easy.